# How to have 2 if statements for row color coding

Tags: php

I am trying to color code table rows if a status is a certain type, that part is working fine, but I want to color code one cell differently if an event date is present, below you will find my IF statement, I am trying to color code the entire row yellow, but if event date is > than NULL it only turns that one cell in the yellow row pink. Hope that makes sense. Not sure how to put the second if statement.

```
if($row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['status'] == 'IN PRODUCTION')
  {
  //////
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['date_created'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['scnum'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['artnum'] . '</strong></td>';
     echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['salesrep'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['company_name'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['invoice_num_op'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . number_format($row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['line_qty']) . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['factory'] . '</strong></td>';
     echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['line_desc'] . '</strong></td>';
     echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['order_po_number'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['license'] . '</strong></td>';
  }
    
    **if($row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['event'] > NULL) {
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="pink"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['event'] . '</strong></td>';
    }**
    
if($row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['status'] == 'IN PRODUCTION')
  {
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>$' . number_format($row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['factory_price'],2) . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>$' . number_format($row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['line_price'],2) . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['putin_prod'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['expected_ship_date'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['ship_from_factory'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['shippedto_customer'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['comments'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"><strong>' . $row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['ship_comments'] . '</strong></td>';
    echo '</td></tr>';
  }else
```

Comment: Have you thought about not just echoing out all the stuff at once but building it up sequentially and only output (aka "render") it once all the decisions are made? i.e. put it into a variable at first

Comment: I have not, since I am a beginner with php, but i will research it for examples. ty but doesn't solve my question at the moment.

Comment: `else if` solves this likely. Just put the greater of your constraints in your first `if` block, and the lesser in your `else if`.

Comment: "more than NULL" is a bit awkward. `NULL` is *not* zero. Its NULL.

Comment: You should not use bgcolor for td, you should inline style css or set a class for the actual color that should be used. You have set the color on the entire row on the tr-element rather than the td.

Comment: Do not use `align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF00"`;  use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Set your style as a variable and 'interpolate' it like so:

```
if($row_ORDERS_NOT_NULL['event'] != NULL){
    $rowStyle=' style="background:yellow" ';
    $cellStyle='';
}
else{
    $rowStyle='';
    $cellStyle=' style="background:pink" ';
}

echo "<tr $rowStyle><td $cellStyle>...";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $rows[] = array("type" => "A", "range" => 13);
        $rows[] = array("type" => "B", "range" => 16);

        foreach($rows as $row){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['type'] ?></td>
            <td style="<?php if($row['range'] > 15) echo 'background:blue;' ?>"><?= $row['range'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This makes no sense. type A or B and range doesn't seem have anything to do with OP's question.

Comment: sry, i misunderstood the question

Comment: No problem. But you maybe could change your answer then? :-)